# What is the main Activity in this Manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am a game designer and unity developer, i rarely do any android native development and i was hoping that you guys can help me with this, in this manifest, what is the main Activity?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" package="com.juiceglobal.lines" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <!-- Google Play -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <meta-data android:name="billing.service" android:value="google.GooglePlayIabService" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- End Google Play -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <!-- voluum -->
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.voluum.sdk.VoluumForwardingBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- End voluum -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <!-- HeyZap -->
    <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapProxyActivity" />
    <!--<activity android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.VASTActivity" />-->
    <receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="package" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- End HeyZap -->
    <!--            -->
    <!--            -->
    <!-- Others -->
    <activity android:name="com.mobilefuel.sdk.AdInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:label="AD" android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService$IabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true">
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 503591776472556" />
    <!--End Others -->
    <!-- TrialPay activities -->
    <activity android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.webcontainer.WebContainerActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.webcontainer.WebContainerPopupActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.trialpay.android.views.videocontainer.VideoContainerActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <!--End TrialPay activities -->
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

i need it in the initialization of another "plugin", i tried :

- com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer
- com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
- com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
- com.soomla.SoomlaApp

And i always get the same error :

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no static field with name='one.of.the.package.above' signature='Ljava/lang/Object;' in class Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;
```

**EDIT**

i can't share the entire class because it's not mine but this is the initialization that gives the error :

```
private const string MainActivityName = "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"; 
public void ReportConversion(string payload)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass cls_UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) 
        {
            using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>(MainActivityName)) 
            {
                AndroidJavaClass cls_MainActivity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.companyName.voluum.Main");    
                cls_MainActivity.CallStatic("ReportConversion", obj_Activity, payload);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Well the one with MAIN. And LAUNCHER.

Comment: that should be **com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity** but it still gives me the same error

Comment: When and where does it give that error?

Comment: their is some problem in importing `com.soomla.SoomlaApp` package.try to re import this correctly.

Comment: @greenapps i edited the post to show where it gives the error

Comment: @Satyavrat how do you know that ?

Comment: your log says that `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no static field with name='com.soomla.SoomlaApp'` this means your class `SoomlaApp` is not found which in reside in  `com.soomla` in this package

Comment: so try again with proper import.

Comment: no no, it gives that error with every package i use even with "native" unity one (i wrote a list in the post), i will edited the post to avoid confusion

Comment: 'but this is the initialization that gives the error'. Where are you doing such an initialisation?

Comment: i have another "normal" script that call "ReportConversion"

Answer (score 0):

`com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity` is the main Activity in your app. The activity with the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in the manifest file is always the main activity (starting activity).

Answer (score 0):

Using **currentActivity** fixed the problem (literally typing currentActivity) when I do this call

```
private const string MainActivityName = "currentActivity"; 
using (AndroidJavaObject obj_Activity = cls_UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>(MainActivityName)) ;
```